# To detect whether string is base64 or directory

Tags: php, base64

it turns out I'm going crazy without knowing how to solve this problem. I have tested several base64 validation functions to detect whether a string is base64 or a path to a file.

```
$path='/img/2015/desert-and-34.jpg';

function itsBase64($data){

   if ( base64_encode(base64_decode($data)) === $data){
       return true;
    } else {
       return false;
    }
}

itsBase64($path);
```

The result is **undefined**, I do not know why.

Maybe the answer is too obvious, but I've been spinning for hours without knowing why the validation does not turn out to be false. can anyone give me a hand?

---

**EDIT:**

It looks like the function is working fine, but I was confusing myself with validation. The problem is that it does not detect that the string is a base64 image and returns false.

That is, the route detects it as false and also detects it as false if it passes a base64 file string.

I do not understand why validation fails, should work, base64 has this structure:

```
$path='data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgAB...
```

Base64 has been generated using canvas in javascript.

Why do not you recognize it as base64?

I've done a little fudge to get out of the way, I hope someone can give me a hand.

```
 if(substr($image, 0,11) === 'data:image/'){     

       $imageWidth = getimagesize($image);


    $image1->base64_to_file($image, $DestJPG);

}
```

A very uncool solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Undefined** is not a php terminology. Where exactly did you get this?

You should try:

```
var_dump( itsBase64($path) );
```

To see the exact value you got back from the function.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that undefined puts it in the PHP error report

Comment: The result is false, but the strange thing is that I change the path for a base64 and it still gives me false, is not it strange?

Comment: My base64 is generated using Javascript canvas with this type of structure:

data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD....

Comment: @DekelI give the answer valid because I have been able to verify that the function delivered false as a result, although now my problem is different, when you can take a look that I have edited the first post with more information, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way,

```
$path='/img/2015/desert-and-34.jpg';

function itsBase64($data){

   if ( base64_encode(base64_decode($data)) === $data){
       return 1;
    } else {
       return 0;
    }
}

echo itsBase64($path); // Output is 0
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not see your messages. It turns out that in reality the result of that function is always false, even though the path variable is a base64. What I do not know is if the problem is to be a base64 jpg generated with javascript canvas, can you give error for this reason?